# Добавление и вывод эмодзи в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, emoji

При отправке POST-запроса на изменение строки `text` с кодировкой `utf8mb4_general_ci` эмодзи отображаются в БД как вопросительные знаки `????`.
В чем может быть проблема?
Как правильно записать строку с эмодзи внутри в БД?
Для информации: если вручную в строку вставить эмодзи, то эмодзи отображается при выводе `echo $row['text'];` как один вопросительный знак. Использую PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как не показали дамп или подключение, перечислю 2 пункта, которые нужно выполнить.

1. Проверить, а лучше ещё раз сменить кодировку и представление для колонки:

```
ALTER TABLE `name` MODIFY `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Теперь можно добавить emoji в таблицу, они должны отображаться нормально.

2. Настроить кодировку при подключении:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8mb4');
```

Теперь emoji должны отображаться в базе нормально и php так же нормально будет работать с emoji.

Comment: Спасибо, помогла установка кодировки в pdo.